# Normal Map Values with ThreeJS GLTF Blender Exporter

Tags: three.js, export, blender, gltf

If I set the "Normal" slider value in Blender under "Geometry" for the texture to 2.0.  I see a normal value of X: 1, Y: -1 when I look at the object in the console log.  Am I missing something?

I'm using ThreeJS R97.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your description of "Normal slider under Geometry", I'm guessing you're talking about Blender 2.79x or earlier, Blender's built-in renderer, material settings, where that slider controls the strength of the applied normal map.

So, a couple of things to talk about here.  First, the glTF exporter doesn't officially support the built-in Blender Render materials, and this slider is not hooked up as you've already discovered.  The development effort for the exporter is now focused on an addon called [glTF-Blender-IO](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO), which works in Blender 2.79 but actually ships pre-installed in Blender 2.80 Beta.

This addon works with the Cycles and Eevee engines using the "Principled BSDF" node, optionally in combination with a few helper nodes such as "Normal Map".  So, the glTF exporter expects to find a normal map hooked up like this:

[image: Normal Map Hookup in Blender 2.79x]

Keep in mind, the glTF format doesn't contain the nodes themselves, but, the exporter will understand this hookup and will write the normal map into the glTF file, along with optionally the base color, metallic, roughness, and emissive maps (via another separate node needed for emissive).

But there's a small wrinkle in this plan, it looks like strength is not hooked up yet.  Blender's "Normal Map" node contains a "strength" parameter, and the glTF format contains a corresponding parameter called `normalTexture.scale` which does the same thing, but, it looks like the exporter is not copying the value from one place to the other.  I filed [issue #241](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/241) on that, and hopefully that will get fixed eventually.

In ThreeJS, the values of X: 1, Y: -1 are intentional for a unit-strength normal map.  ThreeJS normal maps use a different Y-convention from the glTF format, so Y is intentionally flipped when loading a normal map from glTF.  So, to double the strength of it, you would set X: 2, Y: -2.  For now, it looks like assigning this in code (or manually editing a glTF) are the only options until the exporter has a feature added to copy the missing strength parameter.

Comment: Thanks for extensive reply!  I decided to just use userData under the material to export the normal scale value I want.  I can retrieve it and apply when I export it into ThreeJS.  Are you saying for any GLTF model imported from Blender to ThreeJS, I need to have the Y normal scale value negative?  So, when I apply it in javascript, I should make the Y value negative for an imported GLTF model?

Comment: The ThreeJS GLTFLoader should be flipping Y for you automatically.  There are 2 different conventions for tangent-space normal maps, one where green light appears to be hitting the tops of outward bumps, another where green light appears to hit the bottom of outward bumps.  glTF uses the former, and I'm not a ThreeJS expert but my understanding is ThreeJS uses the latter, hence it needs to flip the Y component of all the normal vectors.

Comment: I understand now.  From the looks of the model in game, it seems the ThreeJS glTF exporter is making the adjustments needed, so when I set the normal values in JS, I don't have to negate the Y value.